# How to Pass a Parameter to a Shell Script File That is Used to Execute a Sequence of Commands in Tibemsamdin

Tags: unix, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, tibco, tibco-ems

The command I'm using in Jenkins execute the shell build step:

`./tibemsadmin -server servername:portno -user admin -password pass -script sample.sh`

My Requirement:

How do I pass a parameter to the above `sample.sh` which is already used to execute a set of commands via `tibemsadmin`

Example for my requirement:

`./tibemsadmin -server servername:portno -user admin -password pass -script sample.sh arg1 arg2 arg 3`

If I am passing `arg1` `arg2` and `arg3` like above and build the project Jenkins console output shows **Invalid command line parameter**

The above parameters like arg1 arg2 and arg3 are Jenkins build parameters

For example if `test` is a Jenkins build parameter then I want to pass the parameter to `sample.sh` file as:-

`./tibemsadmin -server servername:portno -user admin -password pass -script sample.sh $test`

tibemsadmin is a `.bat` file I think

So my exact requirement is how to pass any number of Jenkins build `parameters(ex:$test1 $ver $server)` to a shell script `file(sample.sh)` as:

`./tibemsadmin -server servername:portno -user admin -password pass -script sample.sh $test $ver $server`

So is there any possibility or way to pass any number of Jenkins parameters  to sample.sh file similar to my above example.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose I have a sample.sh file:
sample.sh
`echo $1
echo $2`

Jenkins job with build parameters as arg1 and arg2

In Job configure, execute shell command `sh ${WORKSPACE}/sample.sh ${arg1} ${arg2}`

When I run the Jenkins job by passing arg1 and arg2 actual values,
then I can see the arg1 and arg2 values which I have passed printed in console log.

Comment: In my case i have to pass jenkins parameters to a shell script file that has been passed as a script using -script to to execute a set of ems commands. 

For ex: ./tibemsadmin -server servername:portno -user admin -password pass -script sample.sh ${test} ${ver} ${server}

But when i pass jenkins parameter to the above sample.sh jenkins console output shows Invalid command line parameter 

So i want to know how to pass jenkins parameter as an argument *in this line of code*

./tibemsadmin -server servername:portno -user admin -password pass -script sample.sh *in this place*